# Are there better alternatives to the buy and hold method?

Tags: investing, investment-strategies, security, long-term

When purchasing securities of any sort, there always seems to be two pieces of advice - "buy low and sell high", and "buy and hold." Generally speaking, buy low sell high is incredibly difficult for the vast majority of people. Most will get far better results by using dollar-cost averaging, along with holding their investments for long periods of time. But I am curious, are there relatively safe methods that will beat out the buy and hold method when it comes to purchasing securities?

Comment: "buy low and sell high" is not advice.  it's just an absurdly confused comment you hear TV financial talking heads make!  it is literally exactly like saying:  "When playing the lottery, enter only the winning numbers."  It's incoherent.

Comment: "buy and hold" is 10000% useless - if you buy and hold risky stocks!  saying "buy and hold" simply *avoids the basic question* - what the hell should we buy and hold!?  almost always (probably "always") the answer is an ordinary index fund.

Comment: @Fattie "It's incoherent."  Hogwash... Of course it's coherent.

Comment: "Buy and hold" isn't so much a strategy as a recognition that most stocks will increase in value over time. Don't buy a stock with the expectation that you will make a large profit immediately, and don't panic if the price drops a bit soon after the purchase. It says nothing, however, about *what* to buy.

Comment: cheers Ron ..  I think my extensive comments made clear what I meant .. "it is literally exactly like saying: When playing the lottery, enter only the winning numbers." ... and ... it simply avoids the question "what" should we buy and hold.

Comment: The "what" question receives a bit too much attention. Any well diversified portfolio held over a long time will tend to converge towards average market returns the larger it gets

Comment: Obligatory Will Durant quote: "Don’t gamble! Take all your savings and buy some good stock and hold it till it goes up, then sell it. If it don’t go up, don’t buy it."

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we must define what "better" means here. For most investors better in terms of investing strategy means a high return to risk ratio / tradeoff / relationship.

The main reason that buy and hold is overperforming most other strategies is that most securities naturally increase in the long run due to several reasons (technical developments, higher productivity, more free trade, inflation etc.). This effect does not only increase return but also diminishes the risk in the long run, so that the strategy has a great risk/return relationship. A broad diversification will help to reduce risk furthermore.

Answer (score 1):

Rhetorical question: If there was a relatively safer investment alternative that beats the buy and hold method then why would anyone be doing buy and hold?  Did the masses drink the Kool-Aid?

In effect, you answered your own question.   "Buy low and sell high is incredibly difficult for the vast majority of people."

Now if your question was: "It is possible to make a reasonable but lower return with less risk?" then yes, that's possible.  You'd be effectively playing in the middle, never getting the maximum return each year and never taking the full beating of a 35% drop like we experienced in March or the 50% drops in 2000 and 2008.  But that too is "incredibly difficult for the vast majority of people."